# Does ASP.NET has a built-in feature to get user history?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I'm looking for a built-in solution to get what pages the user has accessed through my ASP.NET application.

Here is a simple example :

```
Default.aspx
Page1.aspx
Page2.aspx
Page1.aspx <-- User is here
```

I want to get latest page before current one which in this example is `Page2.aspx`.
Maybe `Master Page` or `ViewState` could help ?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  This smells like a bad practice being born.

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to do, you could also implement it client-side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Request.UrlReferrer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx) to find out the page (or site) that took the user to the current page.

Or [Page.PreviousPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.previouspage.aspx) which tells you the same info but has some caveats:

> When you use the Transfer method or use cross-page posting to transfer
>   processing from one ASP.NET page to another, the originating page
>   contains request information that might be required for the
>   destination page. You can use the PreviousPage property to access that
>   information. If the current page is being rendered as a result of a
>   direct request (not a transfer or cross-post from another page), the
>   PreviousPage property contains null.

However, you only get the previous page. If you want the full history, you will have to enable/implement some sort of tracing in your app.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a "built-in solution".

If you must do this-
If the history is small you could store it in a session.
If bigger, persist to a db.

You could also look into integrating with google analytics.

Comment: This, also, I recommend you write your web-apps to be as stateless as possible however.